# Finding Derivative $f(x)=|x-3|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

I need to find the derivative from the right and the left like,
$$f'_-(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} {f(x_1 + \Delta x) - f(x_1) \over \Delta x}
\\ f'_+(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+} {f(x_1 + \Delta x) - f(x_1) \over \Delta x}$$

When the function is $ f(x) = |x-3|$

and when $x_1 = 3$

I know that the derivative from the left is -1, and the right is 1.

I know that because I can see the slope from the graph, and the answer book said so.

Is it possible to find the answer -1 and 1 using the limit definition I wrote above?

and it's not differentiable at $x_1=3$ is it?

Comment: Do you know how to express $f(x)$ in piecewise form?

Comment: Yes but it isn't differentiable at $x=3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{f\left(x_{1}+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{1}\right)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{f\left(x_{1}+\Delta x\right)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{\left|\Delta x\right|}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0^{-}}-1=-1$$
 if $\Delta x<0$
 . Same argument for $\Delta x>0$
  (we find then $1$
  to the limit).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned we have that

$$ f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 3 \\
\text{undefined} & \text{if } x = 3. \\
1 & \text{if } x > 3
\end{cases}
 $$